# fetch distinct record in a join query in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

one Article has many Comments, and i want to fetch all Articles that have Comments match a condition.

```
Article.find(:joins => :comments ...)
```

fetch the duplicate records
and

```
Article.find(:include => :comments ...)
```

will also fetch the Comment data,I just want to fetch the uniq Article data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using

```
Article.select("DISTINCT articles.*").joins(:comments).where(...)
```

or with syntax you're using

```
Article.find(:all, :joins => :comments, :select => 'DISTINCT articles.*' ...)
```

Comment: Thanks,it generates pretty sql what i want

Answer (score 1):

For example you are trying to fetch all articles with current user's comments

```
Article.joins(:comment).where(:comment => {author: current_user.id}).group_by("comments.article_id")
```